# How to connect hosted mysql database to jsp?

Tags: mysql, jsp

My code:

```
String connectionurl="jdbc:mysql://parthramiz.esy.es/u804261533_impac";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String user="abc";
String passwd="****";
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionurl,user,passwd);
```

Error occur:

> CommunicationsException : Communications link failure Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.

Which connection string used?

Comment: you should provide your code that where you are getting this error.

Comment: String connectionurl="jdbc:mysql://parthramiz.esy.es/u804261533_impac";
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  String user="abc";
  String passwd="****";
  
  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionurl,user,passwd);

Comment: @ParthModi always update your question.no need to write code in comment.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error can occur for few things.

So first thing to check is where your localhost MySQL is running.Check it by typing `\s`.

Next thing make sure that port number is same.

If still you can't make it work then it's probably permission issue.Give permission `grant all on *.*` to identified by "password",then run flush privileges, and then replace 127.0.0.1 with localhost and try to reconnect.

Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql).